# Customized c-offsets-alist override c-file-style in dir-locals

Tags: indentation, cc-mode, directory-local-variables

Assuming I customized my default C indentation settings through `M-x customize-variable c-offsets-alist`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(c-offsets-alist
   (quote
    ((statement-case-open . 0)
     (substatement-open . 0)
     (case-label . +)
     (access-label . -)
     (label . 0)
     (arglist-intro . +)
     (arglist-cont . 0)
     (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
     (arglist-close . 0)))))
```

When I want to edit a project using a specific indentation file, there is (or I can create) a `.dir-locals.el` indicating it:

```
((c-mode . ((c-file-style . "GNU"))))
```

However, the `c-offsets-alist` from my configuration still override the `c-file-style` defaults.

I've tried setting `c-file-offsets` and `c-offsets-alist` in `.dir-locals`, but it didn't work; setting `c-file-offsets` to `nil` had no effect, and setting `c-offsets-alist` to `nil` completely disables indentation.

Is it possible to disable `c-offsets-alist` from having an effect when `c-file-style` is non-nil?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of modifying `c-offsets-alist`, you can modify `c-file-offsets` whose purpose is to set offsets via file local variables.

A small example for a `.dir-locals.el` file:

```
((nil . ((fill-column . 80)))
  (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "GNU")
             (c-file-offsets
              (brace-list-intro . +)))))
```