Unable to override c-offsets-alist in dir-locals.el
I have Emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to modify c-offsets-alist for this particular project with C and C++ source files. I have a c-style and a c-mode-common-hook in my .emacs:
(defconst my-c-style
...
)

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
...
)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)

And I want to override the case label indentation. So I first tried:
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((cc-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
         (c-basic-offset . 4)
         (c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                 (c . c-lineup-C-comments)
                 (substatement-open . 0)
                 (topmost-intro-cont . 0)
                 (inline-open . 0)
                 (case-label . 0)
                 (block-open . 0)))
         (c-tab-always-indent . t))))

This doesn't work, if I type C-h v then c-offsets-alist I see case-label is still at 4. I also found another topic here, suggesting to use c-file-offsets (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44517/18493), which I also tried:
(("cc-mode" . ((c-file-offsets . (case-label . 0))
           (c-basic-offset . 4)
           (indent-tabs-mode . nil))))

However, if I open a *.cxx file and type C-h v for c-file-offsets, I see it is nil. What am I doing wrong?

Solved this one, it seems I had the wrong format for c-file-offsets. This worked for me:
((c-mode . ((c-file-offsets . ((case-label . 0)))
         (c-basic-offset . 4)
         (indent-tabs-mode . nil))))

And yes, I had to use c-mode for C, and will probably need to duplicate that for C++, ugh.
As a side note, I found that you can get Emacs to reload dir-local variables by going to a file in the folder and typing M-x revert-buffer (here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38540/18493). After doing that, Emacs was complaining that I have an unsafe variable in my .dir-locals.el (c-file-offsets, actually). I selected 'y', and then saw that Emacs was helpfully complaining about wrong-type-argument listp 0 or something similar. I checked the docs for the format and, since the FM says it's the same as c-basic-offsets-alist, used that as a model.

If you are editing a .c file, the value of major-mode is c-mode. If you are editing a .c++ file, the value of major-mode is c++-mode.
So if you are trying to use directory-locals that match on mode name (as you seem to be doing), you have to use the appropriate name, otherwise the directory-locals will not apply. Try:
((c-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
            (c-basic-offset . 4)
            (c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                                (c . c-lineup-C-comments)
                                (substatement-open . 0)
                                (topmost-intro-cont . 0)
                                (inline-open . 0)
                                (case-label . 0)
                                (block-open . 0)))
            (c-tab-always-indent . t))))

for a .c file for example.
Depending on your situation, you may be able to use other selectors (subdirs, filenames, all files). But if you want to stick to major mode matching, I don't know of a way to do both .c and .c++ files without duplicating the entries in the dir-local setting.

Well, the part about not being able to modify c-offsets-alist is accurate as far as I can tell, and I can't edit the comment, possibly because there's a reply to it.

Deleted my previous comment and adding another one keeping the info that, as far as I can tell, was accurate:
My understanding is that you can't modify c-offsets-alist in file or directory variables, see https://gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/File-Styles.html for example.
